# How to handle an object observable?

Tags: angular

I am quite new to Angular so apologies if what I'm saying isn't very clear.

I have a service that makes a post request to my backend (node.js and mysql) that checks the submitted login details.
If the login details match, the observable that returns comes with the value it found but if the login details don't appear in the DB, the observable comes back empty.

Thing is, I am unable to apply the length property to the observable object and because of that, I am struggling with showing the proper error message.
Any ideas how to sort this out? is a pipe needed instead of subscribe?

Currently looks like this-

```
  loginchecker(){

    this.DA.logincheck(this.login.value).subscribe(
      data=>{console.log(data);
        if (data.length===0){ //error given here< property length doesn't appear on object
        console.log('does not exist');
        }
        else{
          console.log('exists');
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: What do you see from console.log(data) when login details do not match?

Comment: why check for the length of the object? why not check for a paticular property? or just `if(data)` will also suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the object is empty in  this way:

```
if (Object.keys(data).length===0){ 
        console.log('does not exist');
        }
```